# Is installing/running WordPress any different on Apache than Node.js?

Tags: node.js, wordpress

My client tells me his server is running on Node.js. I'm a WordPress developer, does this fact change the way WordPress gets installed and functions?

Comment: Do you want to install wordpress on node server  ?

Comment: Wordpress runs on php - you can't run wordpress on nodejs - you can install both of them side by side on the same server, i.e. a website/service running nodejs and a separate wordpress site running on apache/php... but i don't think that's what you're asking - it depends what work your client is asking you to do. If they want you to make changes to their nodejs app, then it sounds like you don't have the right skills - if they want a separate wordpress site, then either install it side by side or put it on a different server

Comment: Thanks @Robbie for your clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [npm wordpress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress). It's fairly straightforward and I've had no issues before. This should be your first port of call. Setup a local node server and play around. Good luck.

Comment: This is a wordpress *client* that can be used in a nodejs application to make request to an existing wordpress site. It's not a module for installing/running wordpress on nodejs